# What genre is Futurecop! and Cinnamon Chasers?

Tags: electronic-music, identify-this-genre, synthpop

There is this growing subgenre of EDM characterised by 80's nostalgic themes and lots of oldschool synths. The most prominent artists I'm aware of are: [Futurecop!](https://youtu.be/rYTwRVFHZjo), [Cinnamon Chasers](https://soundcloud.com/cinnamonchasers/8cinnamon-chasers-loving-u), [Anoraak](https://youtu.be/7srCvdjmqo8).

How do you even call that? It's not synth-pop per se, although it's definitely rooted in it, but it sounds more "housy" to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Synth Pop* is a broad label; almost any act that is stylistically or commercially mainstream enough to be 'pop' and produces music based around synthesizer sounds could be said to fall under the umbrella of 'synth pop'. So while we could say that all these acts are 'synth pop', we can also look for more specific terms.

One term that seems to have evolved for a recent wave of artists who nostalgically reference 80s synth-pop and 80s culture is **Synthwave**. This seems a good fit for Futurecop! and Anoraak.

Russ Davies' *Cinnamon Chasers* project (from the few songs I've listened to) seems to have a slightly different range of influences, including 80s and early 90s techno, more recent French House, and mainstream electronic dance artists like Röyksopp. **Nu-disco** is a label that is used for acts that continue to develop the French House sounds and draw from its influences, but if I had to pick one genre label for them I might just go for 'dance' or 'electronic' to be safe!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was guessing about *synthwave* but wanted someone else to confirm. Also *Röyksopp* and *nu-disco* in relation to *Cinnamon Chasers* are a surprise to me, but to the point, as it does seem to be a slightly different genre.

Comment: @wswld I couldn't think of one single genre that was a perfect fit for Cinnamon Chasers. Like many modern acts, they seem to straddle a number of more specific genres, but if you find a better label feel free to edit the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Taken from rateyourmusic.com:

> (…)synthwave is often instrumental and has a "futuristic" theme, with large, throbbing, retro synths. House influenced heavy drums (often side-chained) are also very popular. It draws inspiration from a variety of genres that originated and/or was most popular during the 1980s, including, but not limited to, Synthpop, Progressive Electronic, Italo-Disco, Electro-Disco and other derivative styles. Synthwave albums are generally arranged in a style that is similar to a Film Soundtrack, Film Score, Television Music or Video Game Music album.

[More info and a list of releases from Synthwave artists](http://rateyourmusic.com/genre/synthwave)